# How do I prevent shutdown or suspend during kernel driver firmware update?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, firmware

I have a Linux device driver that implements the firmware update API.  The driver updates the firmware on our device by using I2C commands to update an attached EEPROM.  I use the firmware update API like so:

```c
request_firmware_nowait(
    THIS_MODULE, true, "DEVICE.img", &client->dev,
    GFP_KERNEL, pdata,
    &DEVICE_firmware_callback);
```

The issue I have is that if the system is powered down during this firmware update process then the attached EEPROM is left in a corrupt state and the device controller will not respond properly on the next boot, not even enough to start another firmware update to correct the issue.

I think a clean solution would be to prevent the system from powering down or suspending during this process, but I do not know how to implement that.  Is there a way to have our device driver prevent the system from shutting down while the firmware update is in process?

Comment: A even better solution would be to design the format of the data in your EEPROM so it can be updated safely.  That protects not just against intentional reboots, but also from a kernel crash, a power cycle, or a hardware watchdog.  An method might be to create space for two copies of the firmware, then a new firmware can be written without overwriting the old one.  Once the new firmware is safety written, atomically switch which copy is active.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a reboot notifier along with a completion for this. Whenever you need to perform the firmware update:

1. Register the reboot notifier through [`register_reboot_notifier()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.8/source/kernel/reboot.c#L89).
2. Initialize a completion using [`init_completion()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.8/source/include/linux/completion.h#L32).
3. Start the firmware update. You could do this through a dedicated kthread.
4. When the update is finished, signal completion with [`complete()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.8/source/include/linux/completion.h#L118).
5. Unregister the reboot notifier through [`unregister_reboot_notifier()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.8/source/kernel/reboot.c#L104).

Your reboot notifier will detect a reboot (halt, reboot, power off), and will have the possibility to wait for the work to be done through [`wait_for_completion()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.8/source/include/linux/completion.h#L103) (or one of its variants).

Here's an example module that does exactly this with a dummy kthread that just sleeps for 5 seconds:

```c
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
#include <linux/init.h>       // module_{init,exit}()
#include <linux/module.h>     // THIS_MODULE, MODULE_VERSION, ...
#include <linux/kernel.h>     // printk(), pr_*()
#include <linux/reboot.h>     // register_reboot_notifier()
#include <linux/kthread.h>    // kthread_{create,stop,...}()
#include <linux/delay.h>      // msleep()
#include <linux/completion.h> // struct completion, complete(), ...

#ifdef pr_fmt
#undef pr_fmt
#endif
#define pr_fmt(fmt) KBUILD_MODNAME ": " fmt

static DECLARE_COMPLETION(done_wasting_time);

int my_notifier(struct notifier_block *nb, unsigned long action, void *data) {
    if (!completion_done(&done_wasting_time)) {
        pr_info("Wait! I have some critical job to finish...\n");
        wait_for_completion(&done_wasting_time);
        pr_info("Done!\n");
    }

    return NOTIFY_OK;
}

static struct notifier_block notifier = {
    .notifier_call = my_notifier,
    .next = NULL,
    .priority = 0
};

int waste_time(void *data) {
    struct completion *cmp = data;
    msleep(5000);
    complete(cmp);
    return 0;
}

static int __init modinit(void)
{
    register_reboot_notifier(&notifier);
    kthread_run(waste_time, &done_wasting_time, "waste_time");
    return 0;
}

static void __exit modexit(void)
{
    unregister_reboot_notifier(&notifier);
}

module_init(modinit);
module_exit(modexit);
MODULE_VERSION("0.1");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("Test module: wait for a critical job to finish before"
           " rebooting or powering down.");
MODULE_AUTHOR("Marco Bonelli");
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

Output on my test machine:

```
# insmod reboot_notifier_test.ko
# reboot
[    6.031410] reboot_notifier_test: Wait! I have some critical job to finish...
[    9.998207] reboot_notifier_test: Done!
[   10.003917] reboot: Power down
```