# register_reboot_notifier doesn't notify

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

Playing with LKMs (out-of-tree) I'm trying to perform some work before system reboot using `register_reboot_notifier`, but cant make even this simple code to work:

```c
#include <linux/notifier.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/reboot.h>

static int notify_me(struct notifier_block *nb, unsigned long action, void *data) {
    printk(KERN_INFO "Hey! I'm your reboot notification!\n");
    return NOTIFY_OK;
}

static struct notifier_block reboot_notifier = {
    .notifier_call = notify_me,
    .next = NULL,
    .priority = 0,
};

static int __init notifier_init(void) {
    register_reboot_notifier(&reboot_notifier);
    printk(KERN_INFO "Reboot notifier registered\n");
    return 0;
}

static void __exit notifier_exit(void) {
    unregister_reboot_notifier(&reboot_notifier);
}

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
module_init(notifier_init);
module_exit(notifier_exit);
```

The module successfully compiles and loads indicating that the notifier is registered

```
# insmod reboot_notifier.ko
# dmesg
...
Jun 09 13:26:09 ubuntu kernel: Reboot notifier registered

# reboot
```

, but the `"Hey! I'm your reboot notification!\n"` message never appears in logs after reboot:

```
# journalctl -n 10000 | grep kernel | grep notif
Jun 09 13:26:09 ubuntu kernel: reboot_notifier: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
Jun 09 13:26:09 ubuntu kernel: reboot_notifier: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
Jun 09 13:26:09 ubuntu kernel: Reboot notifier registered
```

Tested it on different systems/kernels:

1. Linux centos 3.10.0-1160.59.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP
2. Linux ubuntu 5.15.0-37-generic #39-Ubuntu SMP
3. Linux desktop 5.15.41-1-MANJARO #1 SMP PREEMPT

Still no luck. Google doesn't help me either.

[Here](https://pastebin.com/GnLA3frB) is a full `journalctl -k -b -1` output after reboot.

Comment: Is it possible that the module is getting unloaded before the notifier is called? You could add a `printk` call to your `notifier_exit` function to check for that.

Comment: @IanAbbott: checked just now, reboot does not unload the module.

Comment: [Works for me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K0KHg.png). Does your `reboot` command actually reboot the machine? If not you can try with `-f`.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli: Tried with `reboot`, `reboot -f`, `sutdown -r now`, `init 6`, `poweroff`, reboot from gui. Just tried on another box (ubuntu 20.04 vps with 5.4.0-110-generic). Boxes are definitely rebooted. But still without the notification.

Comment: @Luis weird... can you share your 5.15 kernel config somewhere? E.G. pastebin.com

Comment: @MarcoBonelli: [Done](https://pastebin.com/YsMfAgY6). It's fresh installed Ubuntu 22.04

Comment: @Luis after some debugging I can confirm that your module works correctly, but the kernel simply does not show the `printk`. Running Ubuntu 22.04 and attaching to the kernel with a debugger I can see that `notify_me` is correctly called. Also, [this code from one of my answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64671908) works fine (change the `msleep` to `30000` milliseconds and test it yourself) and the `printk` messages show. My guess is that in your case the kernel does not bother to flush the buffer out (really unsure why as you have a `\n` there) or maybe doesn't have time to. IDK.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli: I saw that answer before and tried it (just ctr-c ctr-v with no changes) and it did not work for me either. Re-checked again in Centos and Ubuntu with increasing the msleep value, no luck. There is definitely something I don't understand and even don't know where to look =). Thank you for your time anyway

Comment: @Luis ok, that's weird. One thing you can do to check if your `notify_me()` is called at all is to just cause a panic inside it (e.g. `panic("test");`). That should definitely be noticeable. Not sure what you could do about the `printk` though.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli: test with `panic()` shows the `notify_me()` is executed. I even see the `Hey! I'm your reboot notification!` message in `/var/crash/CRASH_DIR/vmcore-dmesg.txt` file after reboot. But the message appears after `[  215.467615] systemd-shutdown[1]: Unmounting file systems.`. I think that's why I don't see my printk in logs and `call_usermodhelper()` doesn't work (that's what I wanted to call on reboot initially)